# How to apply Binary Encoder on a subset of the data frame?

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to use category_encoder for all my object columns. However, I want to apply the transformation within that data frame, keeping my numerical columns as and only encoding the object columns.

As of now, I am able to encode all object columns but the issue is that my code only returns to the encoded columns as it removed the numerical completely.

```
import category_encoders as ce
encoder= ce.BinaryEncoder(cols=df[cat_cols].columns,return_df=False)
#Fit and Transform Data 
enc=encoder.fit_transform(df[cat_cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `ColumnTransformer` Class from `sklearn.compose` [(documentation)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) which allows you to transform only certain columns in your DataFrame while keeping others intact. Specifically, first specify a list of tuples, with the syntax of [('cat_encode', ce.BinaryEncoder(), ce.BinaryEncoder)], in the `transformers` parameter and set the `remainder` parameter to "passthrough". Hope this helps!